# What is going on with Adele's belongings?

Tags: behind-her-eyes

In an early episode, we see that David apparently took away his wife's credit card and phone—or so it would seem.... However, why?

Obviously, out-of-universe, it serves the purpose of making the viewer suspicious that David is abusive, before the more supernatural truth is revealed. However, from David's perspective, how does he expect that taking away his wife's phone and credit card would  prevent her from threatening people with knives or breaking into their houses? For that matter, why would

> Rob

put up with  it? Since "Adele" has a good track record of getting the big things, like e.g. marriage, by threatening David with revealing the details of what happened to Rob, and is after all independently wealthy and not afraid of David, why would he accept these impositions?

Comment: Is this scifi? Wikipedia classifies it as Psychological thriller and Supernatural fiction, but the synopsis and the trailer show only elements of the first one.

Comment: @Taladris - It is fantasy. It admittedly takes three or four episodes before you can be sure, but if you read the other question you would see why. There are not any mistakes in what I wrote....